# Display image on button if the image exists

Tags: ios, swift, image, button

I am working on a image quiz. I have a button that will display either the correct image or the wrong image if there is no correct image. The unique question number comes from an array.

```
if (questionlist[1]correct = [UIImage imageNamed:@"questionlist[1]correct.png"]) {
    Answer4.setImage(UIImage(named: "\(questionlist[1])correct.png"), forState: UIControlState.Normal)
} else {
    Answer4.setImage(UIImage(named: "\(questionlist[1])fourthwrong.png"), forState: UIControlState.Normal)
}
```

Comment: And what is your question? Moreover, fix your syntax first, your first line is not valid Swift code.

Comment: As you so quickly noted Dávid I don't get my if statement to be valid in Swift.

Comment: What are you actually trying to do in that statement? Are you trying to compare the image names as Strings or `UIImage` objects? What objects are stored in `questionlist`?

Comment: I'm trying to compare the image names as Strings.

Comment: Please be more specific. What are the two strings you are trying to compare? `questionlist[1]correct ` cannot be a variable name, hence my question... Moreover, you manage to use String interpolation in your code, so why the Obj-C code with the obviously non-interpolated String in the first line?

Comment: (Thanks for your patience!) I have images called 1correct.png  1wrong.png, 2correct, 2wrong.... The images are connected to the question number. So I use an array with numbers to generate the question. I want to set the image 1correct.png if there is no 1wrong.png. The array questionlist gives the number of the question.

Answer (score 0):

Okay so if I'm understanding your `questionList` array is simply an array of numbers? So `questionList = [1,2,3,etc]`? In that case, you may want to try something like:

```
    let imageName = "\(questionList[1])wrong.png" //for instance 2wrong.png

    if (UIImage(named: imageName) == nil) { // no wrong image exists
        imageView.image = UIImage(named: "\(questionList[1])correct.png")
    } else {
        imageView.image = UIImage(named: "\(questionList[1])wrong.png")
    }
```

Of course this is assuming a correct image exists. It's unclear what you're after, some more information/more code would help.